# Are Types Serializable by Default?

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd

I am reading the book [Learning WCF by Michele Leroux Bustamante](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101626.do). One of the labs is dealing with DataContracts and I am not seeing the expected behaviour of the application as described in the book. Basically an exception should be thrown because a type is not defined as a DataContract and is unable to be serialised.

The type, LinkItem, is defined as follows, without DataContract or DataMember attributes:

```
public class LinkItem
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    // Other properties omitted for simplicity
}
```

The code to host the service is as follows:

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(GigManager.GigManagerService)))
{
    host.Open();
    // Code omitted for simplicity
}
```

When I run the application there is no exception thrown. According to the book, when I visit the XSD schema for the service at `http://localhost:8000/?xsd=xsd2`, I should see `<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ContentTypes">` only when the DataContract attribute is applied. I see the same targetNamespace definition whether the DataContract attribute is applied to the class or not.

My guess is that something has changed in the .NET Framework between the version targeted by the book (2.0) and the version I am running (4.5). As I have only just started to get to grips with WCF I am unable to say for sure. Can anyone more knowledgeable clarify if this is the case or otherwise explain why the exception is not being thrown?

Comment: I was going to ask you the edition of the book, and I think you are on to something with the framework version changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The
>   [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>   is designed to serialize *data contract types*. However, it supports
>   many other types, which can be thought of as having an **implicit**
>   data contract. The following is a complete list of types that can be
>   serialized:
>
> - All publicly visible types that have a constructor that does not have parameters. [...]
> - Data contract types. [...]
> - Collection types. [...]
> - Enumeration types. [...]
> - .NET Framework primitive types. [...]
> - Other primitive types. [...]
> - Types marked with the SerializableAttribute attribute.[...]

See the MSDN article for more information.

Comment: +1  I will be deleting my post as it no longer correctly answers the updated question.

Comment: @HighCore: Thanks for the clarification. I did see that MSDN page earlier but not [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which links to it and has the keyword "implicit". It seems as if I'm not seeing an exception because of the DataContractSerializer class which was introduced in .NET 3.0.

Comment: @DavidVenegoni: I'm not sure what you mean about an updated question. It hasn't been edited since I posted it.

Comment: @Malice I responded almost immediately, and I could have sworn the question at the end read "are all types serializable by default?", you edited it shortly after I posted a response.  It has been a long day, so I could have hallucinated the whole thing, but, in any case, I was mistaken.